# Matrix Row manipulation in Breeze using Scala?

Tags: scala, matrix, linear-algebra, scala-breeze

I've a DenseMatrix

```
1  2  3  0   0   0   0    0    0    
0  0  0  11  22  33  0    0    0    
0  0  0  0   0   0   111  222  333
```

I want to remove the first row and then a last row with all `0`s

```
0  0  0  11  22  33  0    0    0    
0  0  0  0   0   0   111  222  333 
0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0    0
```

How do I achieve this in Breeze ?

Comment: Have you looked at Saddle (https://github.com/saddle/saddle) as a replacement for Breeze?

Comment: @wheaties, I'm curious to know what you like about Saddle over Breeze. I'd like to know how I can make Breeze better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, gather the rows you still want:

```
val subset = matrix(::, 2 to 3)
```

then add the zeroes:

```
val newMatrix = DenseMatrix.horzcat(subset, DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](1,9))
```

I might have mixed up rows and columns in the last line.